# How to print lines with multiple associative arrays and conditions using awk

Tags: arrays, awk, associative-array

I want to print all lines from file 1 where the values of $1 and $4 are found in $1 and $4 of file 2 AND where the value in file 1 $2 is greater than or equal to the value in file 2 $2 AND where the value in file 1 $3 is less than or equal to the value in file 2 $3.

> file 1

```
1   110201809   117658766   a
1   168095261   182305990   b
1   215456074   233436403   c
2   9465687     12905490    d
2   28765309    35235120    e
2   48958595    64702082    f
```

> file 2

```
 1  245371026   249210707   a
 2  937388      46504962    h
 2  937388      162731186   b
 2  2954974     6777829     c
 2  9465687     12996275    d
 2  14539477    44757554    d
 2  14766820    30080818    m
 2  16531332    23584565    n
 2  17340076    26206255    o
 2  18535880    24452180    p
 2  28830071    35289330    q
 2  36206662    47273732    r
 2  48958495    64703082    f
```

Desired output only prints the lines from file 1 that meet the condition.

> desired output

```
 2  9465687     12905490    d
 2  48958595    64702082    f
```

I've tried the following which gave an empty file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1,$4]= $0; b[$2] = $2 ; c[$3] = $3; next }  ($1 $4 in a) && ($2 >= b[$2]) && ($3 <= c[$3])' file2 file1>desired output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by collecting the second and third columns in separate hashes, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```awk
NR==FNR { 
  g[$1,$4] = $2
  h[$1,$4] = $3
  next
} 

($1 SUBSEP $4 in g) && g[$1,$4] >= $2 && h[$1,$4] <= $3
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk file1 file2
```

Output:

```
2  9465687     12996275    d
2  48958495    64703082    f
```

Comment: To be consistent with my initial question, I provided the one-liner using Thor's solution:      awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1,$4] = $2; b[$1,$4] = $3; next} a[$1,$4] >= $2 && b[$1,$4] <= $3' file2 file1>desired output

Comment: @user3146560: You should include an "exists" check as well. See my edit

Comment: Thor, I think I understand what you mean by your edit ($1 SUBSEP $4 in g) but can you comment (or spell out) what each element of the command is doing?

Comment: @user3146560: `$1 SUBSEP $4` is a concatenation of those 3 elements, which is the same as the keys used in the hash addressing, eg. `g[$1,$4]`. The `in g` tests if that particular key is in the `g` hash.